# Is there any way to lunch the all information page of contact person onActivityResult?

Tags: java, android, uri, contacts

I doing this

```
contactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
Intent intentOpenContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, contactUri);
startActivityForResult(intentOpenContact, CONTACT_PICKER);
```

and launch the contact list and got the information I picked

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       switch (requestCode) {
            case CONTACT_PICKER:
                String name = null;
                int phoneIndex = -1;
                int emailIndex = -1;
                String phone = null;
                String email = null;

                try{
                    Uri contactUri = data.getData();
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);

                    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
                         name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    String id = contactUri.getLastPathSegment();//the id you picked
                    Cursor cursorPhone = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                    if (cursorPhone != null && cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
                        phoneIndex = cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA);
                    }
                    Cursor cursorEmail = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                    if (cursorPhone != null && cursorEmail.moveToFirst()) {
                        emailIndex = cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA);
                    }
                    if(phoneIndex != -1){
                        phone = cursorPhone.getString(phoneIndex);
                    }
                    if(emailIndex != -1){
                        email = cursorEmail.getString(emailIndex);
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "name: " + name + " ,phone: " + phone + " ,email: " + email);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

        }}
}
```

But I wish to go the next page of contact person information, then get the information(email or phone) user clicked.
What can I do?

Comment: have you tried the "Retrieve Specific Details for a Contact" in this link http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-details.html
or you can also retrieve a contact and show it in your own activity and allow user to select a specific detail before you save it or use it for whatever purpose you want

Comment: I hope not to load those data to my activity, just work in the uri activity and brought back the useful data.